# convert graph object to dot language in grappa(graphviz)

Tags: graph, graphviz

Is there some way to get dot language that represents graph from the Graph object in grappa(graphviz) library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet is from *DemoApplet1_2.java*:

```
StringWriter theGraph = new StringWriter();
graph.printGraph(theGraph);
theGraph.toString();
```

I think that will give you what you're looking for.